# BeautifulSoup + For loop Zip - How to Try/Except one of them

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Got the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

# Source Sites
mimo = 'https://tienda.mimo.com.ar/mimo/junior/ropa-para-ninas.html'
cheeky = ''
grisino = ''


source = requests.get(mimo).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for name_product, old_price, special_price in zip(soup.select('h3.titprod'),
                                                  soup.select('span[id^="old-price"]'),
                                                  soup.select('span[id^="product-price"]')):
    print(f'Name: {name_product.text.strip()} |  Old price = {old_price.text.strip()} | Discounted price = {special_price.text.strip()}')
```

that outputs the information perfectly:

```html
Name: TAPABOCAS |  Old price = $ 295 | Discounted price = $ 236
Name: REMERA JR TOWN |  Old price = $ 990 | Discounted price = $ 743
Name: CAMISOLA NENA DELFI |  Old price = $ 2.300 | Discounted price = $ 1.725
Name: CAMISOLA JR TRAFUL |  Old price = $ 1.550 | Discounted price = $ 1.163
Name: VESTIDO NENA DELFI |  Old price = $ 2.990 | Discounted price = $ 2.243
Name: SAQUITO JR DESAGUJADO |  Old price = $ 1.990 | Discounted price = $ 1.493
Name: JEGGING JR ENGOMADO |  Old price = $ 1.990 | Discounted price = $ 1.493
```

but...sometimes the special_price loop won't find a discounted price..so i need to make a try/except, tried to "preprocess it"..but i do not know how make it work..

```
special_prices_with_defaults_added = []
for sp in soup.select('span[id^="product-price"]'):
    try:
        special_prices_with_defaults_added.append(sp.text.strip())
    except:
        special_prices_with_defaults_added.append("No default price available")

for name_product, old_price, special_price in zip(
    soup.select('h3.titprod'), soup.select('span[id^="old-price"]'), special_prices_with_defaults_added):
    print(f'Name: {name_product.text.strip()} |  Old price = {old_price.text.strip()} | Discounted price = {special_prices_with_defaults_added}')
```

Wrongly output:

```html
Name: TAPABOCAS |  Old price = $ 295 | Discounted price = ['$\xa0236', '$\xa0743', '$\xa01.725', '$\xa01.163', '$\xa02.243', '$\xa01.493', '$\xa01.493', '$\xa02.925', '$\xa0668', '$\xa0713', '$\xa01.688', '$\xa01.268', '$\xa0593', '$\xa0743', '$\xa01.125', '$\xa03.300', '$\xa02.175', '$\xa0743', '$\xa01.493', '$\xa0863', '$\xa0668', '$\xa0792', '$\xa01.520', '$\xa01.760', '$\xa0696', '$\xa03.150', '$\xa03.520', '$\xa0712', '$\xa01.352', '$\xa01.112', '$\xa01.112', '$\xa01.192', '$\xa02.800', '$\xa02.720', '$\xa03.920', '$\xa01.920']
Name: REMERA JR TOWN |  Old price = $ 990 | Discounted price = ['$\xa0236', '$\xa0743', '$\xa01.725', '$\xa01.163', '$\xa02.243', '$\xa01.493', '$\xa01.493', '$\xa02.925', '$\xa0668', '$\xa0713', '$\xa01.688', '$\xa01.268', '$\xa0593', '$\xa0743', '$\xa01.125', '$\xa03.300', '$\xa02.175', '$\xa0743', '$\xa01.493', '$\xa0863', '$\xa0668', '$\xa0792', '$\xa01.520', '$\xa01.760', '$\xa0696', '$\xa03.150', '$\xa03.520', '$\xa0712', '$\xa01.352', '$\xa01.112', '$\xa01.112', '$\xa01.192', '$\xa02.800', '$\xa02.720', '$\xa03.920', '$\xa01.920']
```

Comment: I cannot access the site (I think only people from Argentine can access it). Can you share the HTML on Pastebin for example. That way I can try it on my computer.

Comment: you use wrong variable in `Discounted price = {special_prices_with_defaults_added}`. It should be `Discounted price = {special_price}`

Comment: BTW: on my computer your code doesn't work because it find `old price` as `product price` but it can't find discounted price. So it is not good idea to search first only all normal prices and next only all discounted prices because second gives empty list and later `zip()` will not work with empty list. Better find all `<li>` with products informations and later work with every `<li>` separatelly to find normal price and discounted price for this one product. This way you can see which product has no price.

Comment: Site was down for a few hours but finally as @furas said it was just a small fix. Will post the fix for future reference. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @furas said... it was just a small fix on the for loop call.

```
for name_product, old_price, special_price in zip(
        soup.select('h3.titprod'), soup.select('span[id^="old-price"]'), special_prices_with_defaults_added):
    print(
        f'Name: {name_product.text.strip()} |  Old price = {old_price.text.strip()} | Discounted price = {special_price}')
```